# Bash: почему «test» не даёт «true» на директории, путь к которой хранится в переменной

Tags: linux, bash

Почему не срабатывает следующий скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/test1

MY_DYR='~/test1'

if [ -d $MY_DYR ]; then
    echo 'TRUE'
fi

echo 'Done!'
```

Ожидал увидеть `TRUE` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что это часть правил `~`-выражения: выражение `~` не срабатывает, если оно заключено в кавычки.

---

### Решение 1

Не заключайте путь с `~` в кавычки.

```
file=~/path/to/file
```

Если вам всё же нужно экранировать часть пути, то сделайте так:

```
file=~/"path with spaces/to/file"
```

---

### Решение 2

Используйте `$HOME` вместо `~`.

```
file="$HOME/path/to/file"
```

---

> [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703720/4223982)